# Understanding Linear Regression

Tags: linear-regression

I am new to machine learning algo and have poor knowledge of statistics. I know this example may not give you correct prediction for volume. However, let's consider I have two features `time` and `symbol` to predict volume. Here is the sample data

```
==========day1============
symbol | time | volume
 mmm   | 0800 | 1000
 mmm   | 0802 | 500
 mmm   | 0804 | 200
 mmm   | 0806 | 100
 mmm   | 0808 | 50
 mmm   | 0810 | 100
==========day2===========
symbol | time | volume
 mmm   | 0800 | 700
 mmm   | 0802 | 200
 mmm   | 0804 | 400
 mmm   | 0806 | 200
 mmm   | 0808 | 500
 mmm   | 0810 | 100
===========day3===========
symbol | time | volume
 mmm   | 0800 | 500
 mmm   | 0802 | 500
 mmm   | 0804 | 700
 mmm   | 0806 | 500
 mmm   | 0808 | 20
 mmm   | 0810 | 10
===========day4===========
symbol | time | volume
 mmm   | 0800 | 1500
 mmm   | 0802 | 500
 mmm   | 0804 | 700
 mmm   | 0806 | 900
 mmm   | 0808 | 1000
 mmm   | 0810 | 300

===========day5===========
symbol | time | volume
 mmm   | 0800 | 9000
 mmm   | 0802 | 1000
 mmm   | 0804 | 3000
 mmm   | 0806 | ?
 mmm   | 0808 | ?
 mmm   | 0810 | ?
```

Let's assume the stock is "trending stock" clearly on day4 and day5 the stock value is going up. I want to predict the volume for the remaining time frame. In this case how will the linear regression calculate the output value for volume?

Comment: Hi ! Are you implementing your own algo ? Or using an existing one ? If using an existing one, wich one ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the linear regression is about finding the best fit for the data points i.e. reducing the error between the actual value and predicted value. In this case the day 4 and 5 induces a lot of error in the model and the actual result might just be the line that fits the points of day1, day2 and day3.